# Is there a javadoc tag for documenting generic type parameters?

Tags: java, javadoc

I've been looking through the javadoc documentation on Sun's site, trying to find if there's a javadoc tag which can be used to document a class or method's generic type signature.

Something like `@typeparam`, similar to the usual `@param`, but applicable to types as well as methods,e.g.

```
/**
 *  @typeparam T This describes my type parameter
 */
class MyClass<T> {
}
```

I suspect there is no such tag - I can find no mention of it anywhere, and the JavaSE API docs don't show any sign of it, but it seems like an odd omission. Can someone put me right?

Comment: To write proper javadocs?

Comment: Be aware that for *most* classes there really is nothing interesting to say about the type parameter, because the type parameter is essentially defined by how it appears in the methods of the object. I'd skip `@param <T>` most of the time and only use it when it's really not clear.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but by that rationale, the same applies to the use of `@param` for method parameters. Sun's coding standards explicitly say that `@param` should be used even if the method parameter's meaning is clear.

Comment: In addition to that. Good API programming should be as self documenting as possible. Does that mean an api does not need a documentation? no.

Comment: The [documentation of @param](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html#param) gives instructions for type parameters. Mind you, Oracle could do a better job of advertising this document.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

It should be done just like this:

```
/**
 * @param <T> This describes my type parameter
 */
class MyClass<T>{

}
```

[Source](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#@param)

Comment: Doh.... OK, that's embarrassingly obvious... it does beg the question as to why the JavaSE classes (e.g. `Collection`) don't use it, though.

Comment: Strange this is, it's not documented in the standard documentation.

Comment: LinkedList uses it: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: It is documented http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javadoc.html#@param

Comment: @skaffman A bit late of course, but it *raises* the question, it does not [beg the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: @Thor84no From your link: Some authorities consider the use of "begs the question" as a way of saying "raises the question" or "evades the question" is no longer mistaken because it has attained such wide usage.

Comment: It's a shame IntelliJ completes like HTML in this case.

Comment: What about actually referring to the type variable in some description text? e.g. `This method returns a new instance of type {@link T}` or similar? (That doesn't work, by the way, and neither does `{@link <T>}`...)

Answer (score 29):

Yes.
Just use the @param tag, and include angle brackets around the type parameter.

Like this:

```
/**
 *  @param <T> This describes my type parameter
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with the [Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io) style guide, it is preferable to describe parameters and their generic types for methods or constructors separately:

```java
/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param data Data parameter description.
 * @param <T> Data type description.
 */
public <T> MyClass(final T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Note that we have two entries for the `data` parameter description. Otherwise, if you only leave `@param data Data parameter description.`, Checkstyle will raise a complaint:

```bash
Number of javadoc parameters different than method signature (JavadocParameterOrderCheck)
Expected @param tag for '<T>'. (JavadocMethodCheck)
```