# Javadoc generation doesn't allows Parameters at JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, parameters, javadoc, jcombobox

I am trying to generate my javadoc with the following variable:

```
private JComboBox<String> monthsBox;
```

My problem is that javadoc brings up the following error:

> type javax.swing.JComboBox does not take parameters
>       private JComboBox monthsBox;

I tried to fix it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015998/1754625) answer like this:

```
/**
* Shows up a list of the available months.
 * 
 * @param<String>
 *            Names of the month.
 */
private JComboBox<String> monthsBox;
```

Still the same problem appears. Maybe I am just searching for the wrong topic.

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Are you using `javadoc` from a Java 7 installation?

Comment: I am using: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/javadoc with the JRE source compatibility: 1.7 . Should I use java-7-openjdk instead?

Comment: Absolutely, generics only appeared in `JComboBox` in Java 7.

Comment: parameters come in parentheses, not angle braces. String isn't a parameter, it's a type

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: it's a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again to Reimeus for your quick advice. Just didnt remind that this type of declaration is available since jdk 7.

Just installed **java-7-openjdk-i386** and used that javadoc. Now everything is working fine (Just needed to delete the @param solution).